# Behat + Selenium2: start testing with init cookie doesn't work

Tags: php, cookies, selenium-webdriver, behat

We are using A/B tests and we must set the cookies which are controlling the pages. I made a simple test:

**cookie.feature**

```behat
@javascript
Scenario: Cookie test
    Given Set cookie "a" = "start" on page "/test.php"
     Then wait 5000
     When Set cookie "a" = "change" and go to "/test.php"
     Then wait 5000
```

**FeatureContext.php**

```php
<?php
// ...

/**
 * @Given /^Set cookie "([^"]+)" = "([^"]+)" on page "([^"]+)"$/
 * @When /^Set cookie "([^"]+)" = "([^"]+)" and go to "([^"]+)"$/
 */
public function setUserCookie($name, $value, $page)
{
    $this->getSession()->setCookie($name, $value);
    $this->visit($page);
}

/**
 * @Then /^wait (\d+)$/
 */
public function iWait($msec)
{
    $this->getSession()->wait($msec);
}
```

**test.php**

```php
<?php echo $_COOKIE['a'];
```

When I run this test then the first page has no cookies! I checked it in Fiddler and the HTTP header doesn't contain cookie first, only the second.

Responses:

1. Notice: Undefined index: a
2. change

How can I set init cookies? (without having to load twice the first page)

Answer (score 3):

The cookie is always sent for the current domain. Since you didn't visit a page yet, the domain has not been set yet. At the moment there's no way to choose a domain for a cookie with mink.

You need to make a request before sending a cookie.

Comment: I made some other tests. If I understand correctly the Selenium driver clear all cookies and session data the first page load of scenario.

I made a static html page with "Please wait, loading..." content, and I load it first, begin of every scenario.